# npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript is not generating any TypeScript files

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` is not generating any TypeScript files, it just making a normal JS project.

I have globally uninstalled create-react-app from my npm as I have seen that suggested as a solution to this before.

Logs:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
npx: installed 80 in 7.19s

Creating a new React app in C:\code\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\code\my-app\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\code\my-app\node_modules\babel-register\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\code\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react@0.14.9
+ react-scripts@0.9.5
+ react-dom@0.14.9
added 912 packages from 647 contributors in 50.852s

Success! Created my-app at C:\code\my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

The created project structure files are all .js, and there is no TypeScript in the package.json.

Comment: Did you ever install create-react-app to global npm modules on your machine? If so you may need to execute `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` first to remove any cached versions of create-react-app

Comment: Yes I have already done that thanks, I mentioned it in the question. I have no idea what may be causing this.

Comment: Can you try `npm init react-app my-app —template typescript` , also can you try doing `where create-react-app`

Comment: Hi @AlexanderStaroselsky - `where create-react-app` gives me `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: and `npm init react-app my-app —template typescript` has the same issue where only JS files are generated

Comment: Had the same problem when running this command from a Git bash console on Windows. 

Running the same command, from a Windows command prompt, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers, this problem sometimes my cause spelling (--template) wrongly or writing (--template) after typescript.
Because if you spell (--template) wrongly then typescript will be skip and your project files will be JavaScript format.

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

That is the correct command.